# Persistance of primefaces components in Spring Webflow

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

I'm having issues with the persistance of primefaces components in Spring Webflow. If the components are instantiated as part of the original page request, everything works fine. However, if the components are instantiated during an ajax request, they're not persisted correctly and when retrieving them later we get an empty object. The effect of this is for example that components on the second tab of a tabview (with dynamic=true) does not work. An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="headIncludes" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="testForm">
            <p:tabView id="myTabView" dynamic="true">
                <p:tab title="Tab One" id="tabOne">
                    <h:panelGroup id="tabOneGroup">
                        <p:commandLink id="linkX" value="Link X" actionListener="#{sandboxBean.testCommandLinkx}" >
                            <f:ajax />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab title="Tab Two" id="tabTwo">
                    <h:panelGroup id="tabTwoGroup">
                        <p:commandLink id="linkY" value="Link Y" actionListener="#{sandboxBean.testCommandLinky}" >
                            <f:ajax /><!-- Only matters if we switch to h:commandLink -->
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When the page is first loaded, a UIComponent representing the commandlink linkX is instantiated and an attribute value for 'actionListener' is saved. When we click "Link X", this attribute value is retrieved again and used to call testCommandLinkx(). This works fine.

When we switch to Tab Two, an ajax request is made and during this another UIComponent representing linkY is created the same way and persisted. However, when we actually click on the commandlink and try to retrieve the actionListener attribute value, we find that there is no such attribute. We instead receive an entirely new object.

If we change to dynamic="false" for the tabView, both commandlinks are created and persisted during the initial page request and everything works fine. If we keep dynamic="true" but use a h:commandLink instead of a p:commandLink, everything also works fine.

Now, I don't really think this is a primefaces bug, as if it was tons of other people would have noted it too. Other people have also tested this particular code fragment without issues. For the same reason I doubt this is a webflow bug. It seems more likely to be a configuration error in our project but I have no idea where. It seems a bit lengthy to include every single configuration file but if you want to see the contents of one just comment and I will add it.

As for versions of different components as people will undoubtedly ask:

- Primefaces: 3.0.1 and all later versions for dynamic tabViews (as this was the first version to support it for real) but it's possible to recreate it in earlier versions if you use another construct that instantiates components in ajax requests.
- Mojarra: 2.0.4 (but I have also tried 2.0.8 and 2.1.6 without improvement)
- Spring Webflow: 2.2.1 (have also tried 2.3)
- Tomcat: 7.0.12 (have tried various other also)

Comment: Try putting `<h:form>` in `<p:tab>` instead. Further those `<f:ajax/>` tags are unnecessary. All PrimeFaces command links/buttons are ajaxified by default already which is supposed to be configured by `ajax` attribute which accepts a boolean.

Comment: Switching the forms around doesn't change anything I'm afraid. The <f:ajax /> is not needed for p:commandLink but it ensures that functionality is the same when switching to h:commandLink. I didn't want people to think the reason h:commandLink works is that it is not an ajax request.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the *"However, when we actually click on the commandlink and try to retrieve the actionListener attribute value, we find that there is no such attribute. We instead receive an entirely new object."* part? Do you mean that you retrieve the component from the view root (or from action event argument) inside the action listener method and then try to get the command component's value from it by `getValue()`? If so, why?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special myself, this is just the inner workings of the primefaces and jsf code. The PrimeFaces CommandLink class extends the jsf class UIComponent (through UIComponentBase, UICommand and HtmlCommandLink). This UIComponent class has a StateHelper object where the actual attribute values are stored in a map. When p:commandLink is rendered, StateHelper.add("actionListener", "#{sandboxBean.testCommandLinkx}" ) is called. However, when we click the commandLink and StateHelper.get("actionListener") is called, null is returned as the attribute map is empty.

Comment: And as mentioned before, this only happens if the p:commandLink was rendered during an ajax request. If it's rendered during the full page request, when clicking the link StateHelper.get("actionListener") correctly returns the persisted value.

Comment: Uhm okay, what functional requirement are you trying to achieve which broke due to this? The question/problem is in general pretty confusing and hard to understand, you seem to be talking in the context as if you're the PrimeFaces component library developer, not the PrimeFaces component library user. We in general expect questions which are described in the context of the component library user.

Comment: I'm trying to use components inside of a p:tabView with dynamic="true" to avoid having to load the content of all tabs as soon as the page is loaded. Another scenario is where we use a p:treeView and the node selection determines which component is loaded in the center panel. In general any component loaded during an ajax request is completely broken by this.
I'm not a primefaces developer, but I've been digging into the code to try to find the reason (and maybe a fix) for this issue.

Comment: I just took the effort to try to reproduce your functional problem. I copypasted the exact markup and stubbed a backing bean. It just works. The links in the both tabs invoke the action properly. The only difference is that I don't use Spring. Just standard Java EE.

Comment: Yeah it definitely seem to be specific to SWF. Gonna try to set up a demonstration project according to https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-webflow-issues#readme and maybe the spring guys can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be a bug in Spring WebFlow and is actually fixed in 2.3.1 that was release March 27th.